# How to connect from Google Apps Script to MySQL database based on Wordpress?

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, google-apps-script

I have a question. I would like to connect Apps Script to my Wordpress MySQL database but have some issue. Code bellow return error "ReferenceError: Lib is not defined". How can I fix it? My goal is to execute SQL queries on schedule time via Apps Script and past it down to spreadsheet. What is wrong with that code?

```
var server = "***"
var dbName = "***"
var username = "***"
var password = "***"
var port = ***

function createConnection(){

var url = "jbdc:mysql://" + server + ":" + port + "/" + dbName;
var conn = Lib.getConnection(Jdbc).getConnection(url, username, password);
var stmt = conn.createStatement();
var rs = stmt.execute("SELECT * FROM wp_post LIMIT 100")

console.log(rs)
conn.close();

}
```

Comment: Looks like you don't how a Library installed with the name Lib.   But you don't really need one to use JDBC

Comment: If I change line with Lib to "var conn = Jbdc.getConnection(url, username, password);" I have got "ReferenceError: Jbdc is not defined
createConnection @ Database_Connection.gs:10" error. What you suggest me to do?

Comment: it's Jdbc... spelling counts in programming https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/jdbc/jdbc

Comment: Okay, you are right. I spell that wrong but after I correct that it return "Exception: Connection URL uses an unsupported JDBC protocol." error. How about that?

Comment: So now search for Jdbc error: `"Exception: Connection URL uses an unsupported JDBC protocol`  There are a few references

Comment: Okay, I figure it out and now it start working but it returns only simple sql queries but with bigger one with around 10 LEFT JOINS and etc it return "Exception: Unknown column 'wp.ID' in 'field list'" error. This is 1:1 query that work in MySQL database. I only change double quote to single ( " - > ' )

Comment: If you want help you will most like need to update your example.